# How to clear the clipboard everytime I add something to it?

Tags: python, tkinter, random

I am working on a password generator. I have a button that generates the password and a button that copies it to the clipboard.
The problem is: Every time I generate another password and then add it to the clipboard it just gets added to the other password.
If I had the password 123ok and copied it to the clipboard but then generated 456ok and copied this one to the clipboard I would have 123ok456ok.

That´s my code:

```
import string
import random
import tkinter as tk

letters = string.ascii_letters
numbers = string.digits
symbols = string.punctuation

chars, nums, syms = True, True, True

evy = ""

if chars:
    evy += letters
if nums:
    evy += numbers
if syms:
    evy += symbols

length = 8

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title("Password Generator")
window.configure(background="black")


def generate():
    for x in range(1):
        global password
        password = "".join(random.sample(evy, length))
        pwd = tk.Label(text=password, foreground="green", background="black", font=16)
        pwd.pack()


genBtn = tk.Button(window, command=generate, text="Generate Password")
genBtn.pack()


def copy_clip():
    window.clipboard_append(password)
    window.clipboard_clear()


copyBtn = tk.Button(text="Copy the password", command=copy_clip)
copyBtn.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

````
import random
import tkinter as tk

letters = string.ascii_letters
numbers = string.digits
symbols = string.punctuation

chars, nums, syms = True, True, True

evy = ""

if chars:
    evy += letters
if nums:
    evy += numbers
if syms:
    evy += symbols

length = 8

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title("Password Generator")
window.configure(background="black")

password = ""  # Initialize the password variable

def generate():
    global password  # Use the global password variable
    password = "".join(random.sample(evy, length))
    pwd = tk.Label(text=password, foreground="green", background="black", font=16)
    pwd.pack()

genBtn = tk.Button(window, command=generate, text="Generate Password")
genBtn.pack()

def copy_clip():
    if password:
        window.clipboard_clear()  # Clear clipboard
        window.clipboard_append(password)
        window.update()  # Update clipboard

copyBtn = tk.Button(text="Copy the password", command=copy_clip)
copyBtn.pack()

window.mainloop()```

Try this instead
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).